# Worker is not finished while sending message to intermediate worker

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, d

I am using "programming in D" to learn about D language. I wrote a simple program that spawns a worker and sends it a number to receive its square as a string. The worker 1 gets the number squares it and sends to worker 2 (a different function) to get casted as string which is returned to the worker 1 and thus it returns it to the main function call. I can write the whole thing in a single thread. I wrote it to understand about workers better. I used `receive` to get the worker 1 act as per the input. The program is as follows

```
import std.stdio;
import std.concurrency;
import std.conv;
import core.thread;

void main() {

  foreach (int num; 1..100) {
    auto square_tid = spawn(&square);
    square_tid.send(num);
    auto square = receiveOnly!string();
    writeln(square);
  }
}


void square() {
  static i = 0;
  receive (
       (int num) {
         auto square = num * num;
         writeln("sqaure : Comes in with " , num , " for " , ++i , " time");
         auto stringWorker = spawn(&stringConverter);
         stringWorker.send(thisTid, square, ownerTid);
       },
       (Tid tid, string str) {
         writeln("comes in string");
         send(tid, "hello");
       });
}

void stringConverter() {
  static i = 0;
  auto params = receiveOnly!(Tid, int, Tid)();
  auto stringified = to!string(params[1]); // Stringify the square
  writeln("string : Comes in with " , params[1], " for " , ++i , " time");
  params[0].send(params[2], stringified); // params[0] - square function tid, params[2] - main function tid
}
```

I can receive the main function tid and directly send the string back. But when I return to the worker 1 it gets struck and doesn't proceed further. How can I make a thread to receive input from master thread and also from the slave thread. Another few questions about threads :

- If I want to send -1 as the data to my worker without exiting it. How can I do it?
- Is it ok to use a single worker for the whole process or I can use multiple workers as I did in the foreach loop?
- The book uses the following code. Why does it have the value >= 0 as its obvious in the code.

```
    import std.stdio;
    import std.concurrency;
    import std.conv;

    void main() {
      Tid worker = spawn(&workerFunc);
      foreach (value; 1 .. 5) {
        worker.send(value);
        double result = receiveOnly!double();
        writefln("sent: %s, received: %s", value, result);
      }
      /* Sending a negative value to the worker so that it
       * terminates. */
      worker.send(-1);
    }

    void workerFunc() {
      int value = 0;
      while (value >= 0) {
        value = receiveOnly!int();
        double result = to!double(value) / 5;
        ownerTid.send(result);
      }
    }
```

Correct me if I am wrong in any of the terminologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of task is better to use std.parallelism

```
import std.stdio;
import std.parallelism;

void main() {
    auto squares = new long[100];
    foreach(i, ref elem; parallel(squares)) {
        elem = i * i;
    }

    writeln(squares);
}
```

And there is no problem with sending -1 to worker thread, it will not exit thread only when it is explicitly ask.

And here is a modified version of your attempt:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.concurrency;
import std.conv;

void main() {

    foreach (int num; 1..100) {
        auto square_tid = spawn(&square);
        square_tid.send(num);
        auto square = receiveOnly!string();
        writeln(square);
    }
}


void square() {
    static shared i = 0;
    receive (
        (int num) {
        int square = num * num;
        writeln("sqaure : Comes in with " , num , " for " , ++i , " time");
        auto stringWorker = spawn(&stringConverter);
        stringWorker.send(thisTid, square, ownerTid);
        receive ((Tid tid, string str) { writeln("comes in string"); send(tid, "hello");});
    });
}

void stringConverter() {
    static shared i = 0;
    auto params = receiveOnly!(Tid, int, Tid)();
    auto stringified = to!string(params[1]); // Stringify the square
    writeln("string : Comes in with " , params[1], " for " , ++i , " time");
    params[0].send(params[2], stringified); // params[0] - square function tid, params[2] - main function tid
}
```

**UPDATE explanation**

the `square` function in your code ends after `receive`. So it never try the next block with `(Tid tid, string str)` part. This is why I put it inside the first part of `receive`.

With each call of `spawn` you creating new thread. And because D use TLS by default the `static` keyword is useless in your example. Because in every new thread `i` would be `0`. This is why I use `shared` keyword.

**UPDATE 2**

here is a version which could explain more how things works:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.concurrency;
import std.conv;

void main() {

    foreach (int num; 1..100) {
        auto square_tid = spawn(&square);
        square_tid.send(num);
        auto square = receiveOnly!string();
        writeln(square);
    }
}


void square() {
    shared static i = 0;
    bool end = false;
    while(!end) receive (
        (int num) {
        auto square = num * num;
        writeln("sqaure : Comes in with " , num , " for " , ++i , " time");
        auto stringWorker = spawn(&stringConverter);
        stringWorker.send(square);
    },
    (string str) {
        writeln("comes in string");
        ownerTid.send(str);
        end = true;
    });
}

void stringConverter() {
    shared static i = 0;
    auto params = receiveOnly!(int)();
    auto stringified = to!string(params); // Stringify the square
    writeln("string : Comes in with " , params, " for " , ++i , " time");
    ownerTid.send(stringified); // params[0] - square function tid, params[2] - main function tid
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can use parallel just wanna learn about message passing between threads :) Could you please explain why wrapping the receive call with tid and string inside that of int makes it work. Why do you make i shared as they are independent static variables for the functions

Comment: If you want something learn [this](http://forum.dlang.org/group/digitalmars.D.learn) is ideal place for questions. I will edit my answer to explain why I add shared and why you need to put it inside recive call